# Assembly MIPS 32 bit - Memory Addresses

Tags: assembly, mips, computer-science, cpu-architecture, mips32

I'd need a hand on this particular assembly MIPS 32 exercise, this is the code I'm given:

```
     .data  0xFEC
     .half -127, 0x127
arr: .word -40
     .space 5
     .align 3
str: .asciiz "ABBA"

     .text
     ...
```

I have to represent the content in hex format and the correspondent addresses of the memory area that is going to be affected by the execution of the aforementioned code(Keeping in mind that the ASCII code for "A" is 65).
Other than that I should have to determine:

- Value that the assembler will give to the *str* label
- Value returned on the first use of syscall *sbrk*

Any help would be really appreciated, thanks in advance!

Comment: Which part is causing you problem?

Comment: @jester I don't know how to represent the memory area in hex format, I just know that the *.data <...>* tells me that the memory area for data starts at address 0xFEC. Other than that I don't know what value will the assembler give to the *str* label, I mean, is it going to give a growing address of +4 for every line from data to str or is there another method? Thanks

Comment: Yes it will assign growing address, but of course based on how much each directive allocates.

Comment: Perfect, thanks @Jester. One last thing, about the *sbrk* syscall, I know that it returns the address of a block of memory for dynamic memory allocation, but from the code I'm handed, how can I know what value it will return?

Comment: Presumably it will return the first address after all your data (possibly aligned to some boundary)